# My cat occasionally wounds himself. Should I be worried?

Tags: cats, behavior, injury

To clarify I don't let my cat go outside and he sometimes runs around the house and has several hiding spots I don't know to this day. However my cat occasionally gets a wound (Usually near his head). He recovers on his own and doesn't seem disturbed by the wound in the slightest (He does get disturbed when I try to get a good angle on the wound to properly see it.) But I'm worried that there may be some sort of numbing issue near his head which worries me.

Should I be worried or is it normal for cats to not to be disturbed by their wounds?

Comment: if your cat gets injured by beeing inside your house you should definitely be worried,what has the vet to say about this?.cats can hide a massive amount of pain and not show it to the owner so you do need to know what to look for.

Comment: Are these wounds always at the same spot? For example, always at the chin, back of the ears, in front of the ears, back of the head? And what do the wounds look like? A scratch under the fur, a spot where the fur is lost? You should absolutely try to find the cause of those wounds. They can be self-inflicted (by scratching due to parasites) or happen when your cat squeezes through a hole with sharp edges or maybe even by other animals (mice or rats maybe).

Comment: They are usually on the head and my guess would be the sharp edges too. As for the Vet last time he got a checkup the vet said he was perfectly healthy and a very docile cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My cat used to do exactly the same thing. We discovered it was probably from a sharp mirror in the bathroom that he loved to rub up against.

Check with your vet first to make sure it isn’t another issue like parasites, but also check your house for anything sharp your cat may be scratching itself on. Additionally, if you do see a wound, keep a close eye on it to make sure it doesn’t turn into an infection.